Polycom VVX 500 Won't pick up incoming line
I've installed a 3cx server in google cloud and I have a polycom vvx500 I've provisioned to it from my home internet to test some configurations.
I can pick up the handset and make outbound calls perfectly.
The phone rings when there's an inbound call to its ring group.
The problem is if I pick up the handset or press the answer button when I see an inbound call, nothing happens.
The inbound call keeps ringing and the polycom phone does not pick up the line.
Any ideas what may be causing this?
Things I've tried:

Enable QoS, set polycom device to highest priority
FWD ports 5060-5061
FWD ports 9000-10999
Make sure SIP ALG is disabled
Reprovision device
Factory reset and reprovision device

